# How do I upvote a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

In StackExchange, I noticed numbers to the left of comments on an answer. The last comment was the one that answered my question. How do I give that comment an upvote?

Comment: hover over a comment and see an arrow appear on the left of it, then move over to it and click it

Comment: first, this question do not belong here, but i suggest you to check this. http://superuser.com/help/privileges

Comment: @FranciscoTapia so how many does he need to upvote a comment?

Comment: I have tried hovering all over the comment, especially over the '3' which is already there, and I don't see an arrow to click. Perhaps I need a certain level of privilege to upvote a comment?

Comment: @barlop, i was wrong, ive a missunderstood, i got your point ;)

Comment: @mulevad, suggets some edits and you will get some points i bet 15 is the answer.

Comment: That's it! I finally found the official explanation on the "Vote Up" page at the top. I completely overlooked it.
    Privilege Type: Moderation Privilege
    Awarded At: 15 Reputation 
Thank you @barlop  FranciscoTapia (I can't "answer" this in this forum, but I consider it answered.)

Answer (score 3):

As you've already found out by yourself, you [require 15 reputation to upvote comments](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up).